# How to compare a number in an array to that same array's entire line-up

Tags: java, arrays, random, compare

In school we got a task where we had to create an array with 20 slots, and fill it with random numbers anywhere between 1 and 100, with a random number generator, something like this like this:

```
int arr[] = new int[20];

for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 100) + 1
}
```

Then we had to find the largest in the line-up that this random number generator made. Like:

```
int maximum = arr[0]; 
/*a random integer that's initialized after the line-up is made,
 *since initializing ahead of that would be problematic,
 *and then starts with the first value in the array
 */

for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (maximum < arr[i]) {
        maximum = arr[i]
    }
}
```

Then we just print the contents of the array, and the newly found maximum number from the array. I also got creative a little bit here; purely for aesthetic reasons, you'll see:

```
System.out.println("The line-up of random numbers generated into the array:");
for (i = 0; i < arr.lenghth; i++) {
    if (i == arr.length - 1) {
        System.out.println(arr[i]);
    } else {
        System.out.print(arr[i] + ", ");
    }
}
```

(If you didn't catch it; it prints all elements of the array in the same line, separated with a comma and space. Then, when it reaches the end, it prints it in the same line, but anything beyond will be in the next line, and it also doesn't print a comma and/or space. Purely for aesthetics.)

This is where I got even more creative; I wanted to put all the integers into growing order. It was fairly trivial with insertion sorting - after some research. (If you'll excuse me, I'll skip over typing the code out for that, because 1) it worked, 2) it has some non-English phrases, as I'm not natively English, therefore my variable naming is also not in English, especially if this was meant to be sent back to the teacher, 3) frankly the built in code sampler in Stack Overflow isn't great - coming from NetBeans -, but whatever. The point is, no trouble here.)

My trouble started, when I saw, that whole bunch of the numbers were the same. I figured *"How about we change that."* And total disaster. Not only did it not change the numbers, it made even more. That's karma, if you ask me.

Anyways, I went *"Okay, let's do some research."* And my research machine, Google, didn't have the correct, or otherwise had the exact same solution, as I was trying. That is:

```
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (j = i+1; j < arr.length; j++)
        if (arr[i] == arr[j]) {
            arr[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 100) + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, before you go *"Just change >>arr[i]<< to >>arr[j]<<"*, well, no dice there either.

As I was thinking about it, I thought *"Why can't I just go through all of the values one-by-one, then go through all of the values again, and compare them to the value I initially picked?"* But then realized, that this algorithm does just that, and the problem lies elsewhere. But for the love of my life, I can't figure it out.

Also, if anyone's interested, here's the entire code; but without the broken code:

```
package searchformax;
public class SearchForMax {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //initialization
        int arr[] = new int[20]; //array, and it's set length
    
        //random number generation
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 100) + 1;
        }
    
        int maximum = arr[0]; 
        /*a random integer that's initialized after the line-up is made,
         *since initializing ahead of that would be problematic,
         *and then starts with the first value in the array
         */
    
        //the search for the actual maximum number
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] > maximum) {
                maximum = arr[i];
            }
        }
    
        //userfriendliness
        System.out.println("The line-up of random numbers generated into the array:");
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (i == arr.length - 1) {
                System.out.println(arr[i]);
            } else {
                System.out.print(arr[i] + ", "); 
            }
        }
    
        //presenting the largest nummber
        System.out.println("The largest number from these: " + maximum);
    }
}
```

Now, again, this is not strictly necessary, just to please my appetite for more knowledge - seriously, we are being so slow, especially since, in my country, every high-school student has been sent home for home-school; yes, you could say *"Be careful with self-education."*, but, don't worry about it. And, when it came time to send I wasn't going send it with the extra code, and stripped it out when I did. Still, I'm curious, as to where my problem lies, or if it's something that is unfixable due to the nature of Java, or something.

Comment: Just from reading the beginning and the first transition, it seems like you have a lot of unnecessary noise (storytelling) in your post. Most people are not interested in this and only want the problem stated in as short and concise explanation as possible. A lot of people get turned off by long posts. I'm sure this post could be shortened by a lot if you just stuck with the main problem. Just my two cents.

Comment: You failed to succinctly describe your actual problem. You have a lot of fluff about how you ended up where you are and that you have a problem, but you gloss over the core of your problem. Please rephrase your question so the focus is on the problem, provide a [mre] and the actual results, and describe how or why those results deviate from your expectations.

Answer (score 1):

### Misusing Math.random()

> `arr[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 100) + 1`

This isn't, actually, the right way to do that. The problem is this: If I give you a standard die (with 6 sides), and I ask you to give me a uniformly distributed random number between 1 and 4, and you do this algorithm: "Okay, well, I'll roll the die, and then if I get 5 or 6, I'll have those 'overflow' into 1 and 2, so if I roll a 1 or 5, I answer 1, a 2/6 I answer 2, and for a 3 I answer 3 and a 4 I answer 4". You can clearly see that is **not** uniform. The exact same problem, except which much bigger numbers, applies to what you are doing: In the end, computers are binary and there is a specific non-infinite amount of answers that `Math.random()` could possibly give.  If that is not exactly divisible by 100 (and, it isn't), then some numbers will come up more often than others. It won't be by a lot, but it's not truly random.

That's why this is the right way:

`arr[i] = rnd.nextInt(100) + 1`

where `rnd` is the result of `Random rnd = new Random();` (you make an instance of Random once and then keep calling it to obtain more and more random numbers).

### The actual question - pick random, but unique, numbers

Buried deep into your story we get to the actual question, which appears to be:

I want to fill an N-sized array with random numbers chosen from between 1 and R (inclusive) - but without duplicates.

Where N = 20 and R = 100 in your question.

### The problem with your algorithm (reroll duplicates)

The strategy you've (badly) implemented is to just keep checking if the array you got is unique, and if not, to reroll numbers. Unfortunately, you haven't taken into account that rerolling the 15th number in your 20-sized array may then cause it to be equal to the 1st number. Theoretically, it could take forever for you to get to a unique array. Imagine N=100 and R = 90, then it **would** run forever (you can't generate 100 unique numbers between 1 and 90, of course). A for loop like you wrote **cannot** run forever, which is therefore neccessarily wrong: Your approach would require some loop construct which could theoretically run forever.

The right way to do it is not to first roll up 20 numbers and then start checking. It's to roll 1 number, then check if that number is addable (unique), which is trivial: You have no numbers yet, it's addable. Then to move on: Roll the number for the 2nd slot, but keep rolling until the number is unique.

Note that this algorithm is quite inefficient when N is equal to R or only a little smaller: If N=1000 and R=1000, then for that last number, you're literally rolling about 1000 times (checking it against 999 entries *every time*) until you get lucky and roll the one number that's still available. And, of course, if N is below R, it runs forever. You should probably write an `if` someplace to abort early instead.

There are other, easier ways to do this:

### Enumerate-and-shuffle

Enumerate every number in the 'pick range' (so, for your question, make a list of `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, .... 100]`. Then shuffle this list using e.g. `Collections.shuffle`, then just pick the first N numbers from it, which gives you N uniformly distributed *and unique* random numbers between 1 and R.

This works well unless the 'pick range' is very large (let's say 100k+), because if it is very large you'd need to make a very large list and wait a relatively long time to shuffle that list.

### Build-and-shuffle

Another algorithm has the opposite effect: It works well if R is large and N is small:

The aim is to maintain in a smart way the actual 'number line' of valid options: Let's go back to a very simple R=6, N=2 case. For the first number, the valid options are `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`. Let's say it's a 4. Then for the second number, valid options are only `[1, 2, 3, 5, 6]`. In other words, `.nextInt(5)` is needed for that second roll, not `nextInt(6)`, but the result of `nextInt(5)` needs to be mapped. The possible outputs are `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]` and that needs to be mapped to `[1, 2, 3, 5, 6]`.

To do that efficiently you need to store your already chosen numbers in sorted order (imagine R=100, N=20, and so for you have 18 and 10. If `nextInt()` then produces 16, you need to adjust that to *19*; you don't know that the presence of 18 in the already-chosen list of numbers means you need to increment the result of your nextInt call until after you've incremented it due to 10 also already having been chosen, which is why it needs to be sorted). You can keep a list 'self-sorting' (that it inserts in the right place) efficiently, and not with insertion sort - see `TreeSet<Integer>` which is a data structure that efficiently does it. It involves trees, it gets very complicated.

Then, at the end, you have a sorted list of N numbers chosen randomly from 1-R with no duplicates. To then make that 'fully random', just shuffle this list.

This algorithm is *far* more complicated than the previous one.

A fully flexible 'always efficient' implementations uses the second algorithm if N is small and R is large, and uses the first if R is small, or N and R are in the same ballpark, and throws an exception if N>R.